# Hide time value from date type column when editing in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, gridview

I've got a GridView that displays dates as "dd-mm-yyyy" which is what I want, but when editing I get "dd-mm-yyyy 00:00:00". Since I am using a date data type, I don't want the time included when editing since my validation for date will only accept "dd/mm/yyyy". Am I using the wrong data type or do I need to change this line?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GameDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

This GridView is taking data from a database.

Comment: can you post the complete markup for this field from your gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the GridView field is a template Field?  If so give this a try:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Game Date" SortExpression="GameDate">
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GameDate","{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>' ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GameDate", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Of all the answers, this was the one that works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use formatting

```
<%# (DateTime.Parse(Eval("GameDate").ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) %>
```

Comment: I got back "No method for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument"

Comment: That worked but now I have the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: Now when I edit a row and hit update, the date column becomes empty. Then when I try to edit that row again it says `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: you would have to use this both Item and Edit Item  Templates; you need to understand the concepts

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert(varchar(30),GameDate,103) as GameDate
```

Use convert function in database select query. It will remove time.

Comment: Ive put my select statement as `SELECT * FROM [MatchStats] ORDER BY [GameDate] DESC
Convert(varchar(30),GameDate,103) as GameDate
` but get a syntax error message near convert

Comment: Instead of select * put individual column names. The convert function needs to be placed after select as select convert(varchar(30), gamedate,103),..<rest of the column names>

Comment: I did this `SELECT Convert(varchar(30),GameDate,103) as GameDate, [Id], [HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeScore], [AwayScore], [GameDate] FROM [MatchStats]
ORDER BY [GameDate] DESC` and got back 'Ambiguous column name GameDate'

Comment: `SELECT Convert(varchar(30),GameDate,103) as GameDate, [Id], [HomeTeam], [AwayTeam], [HomeScore], [AwayScore] FROM [MatchStats]
ORDER BY [GameDate] DESC` use this query